# I can't find Bot Channels Registration in App registrations and update client secret

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

I have a set of bot applications that were created more than 2 years ago (type: Bot Channels Registration).

One of the applications has expired client secret and I need to update it, but these applications are not in the list of `App registrations`.

I tried to follow this path: `My Bot Channels Registration -> Configuration -> Microsoft Asp ID (Manage Password)`. I was again transferred to `App registrations`, which does not have my bot. I have administrator rights, there are no other app directory.

Comment: Copy the [**Microsoft App Id**](https://i.imgur.com/hicLb6U.png) of Bot Channel Registration and search it in App Registrations by selecting  **All Applications** like [this](https://i.imgur.com/ZeFHDdS.png).

Comment: @Sridevi, Thank you, but I have already tried to search for him both by name and by Microsoft App ID. I also see this application in `All resources`. But it is in `App registration` that it is missing.

Comment: @Sridevi, Interestingly, I can see the bots that have these secret keys active in `App registrations`. In addition, I suspect that there were users on this account before who could create these bots, but those users have long been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here 's what the caliper team replied about this:

> We checked the App registrations for AppID: xxxxxxx-XXXX-XXX-XX
> Federico confirmed that the AppID is not present in Azure AD. If an
> app registration is deleted before 30 days ago or permanently deleted.
> That app cannot be restored in azure portal. You will have to create
> new App Registration. In Bot also you can’t update the APP ID once it
> is created. So, you will have re-create the Boot also.

About just updating the key without creating a registration:

> In this case since the application it doesn’t exist at all anymore, there’s no way to update the client secret just because the application is no longer available.

As a result, this bot is irretrievably lost, although it is in azure, but it is impossible to create an app registration for it.

---

Continuation of the story:

It turns out that these `app registrations` are visible here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications

Keys can be added using it:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{application-id}/microsoft.graph.addPassword](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/%7Bapplication-id%7D/microsoft.graph.addPassword)

But now we have another problem, it turns out that this user simply does not have rights to this application, although this user created them, he sees other applications, no other Directory was created. After we were able to prove that the applications were not deleted, the support team started working a little better. But so far their team can't explain how it happened. We are waiting for the continuation of the story.

Comment: The azure team, as always, is not trying to solve the issue, but is trying to get rid of the problem by shifting responsibility to something else.

Comment: Perhaps someone is wondering where they reported that App Registration was deleted, they also lied. Since later I did the removal of App Registration for another bot, and there I got a 401 error of a completely different type. At the same time, they have an error there, 401 was returned in the description, 400 in the request status =(